# Change virtual QEMU image location

Tags: qemu

I've got an existing QEMU Virtual Server running on Fedora 11.  Having troubles trying to find out how to change the location of where the Virtual Images are stored.

Can anybody provide any help please?

Thanks in advance!

I'm also new to Linux Server Administration - n00b in other words - so this might seem lazy but I need to know commands or where to look

Answer (score 1):

QEMU is usually run from shell, even if a number of GUI exist all around. Try doing a `ps aux | grep qemu` and see if you can find in the output the commandline for qemu binary (look for `-hdc` option).

Answer (score 1):

I searched this question when I moved an img file to a different place causing virt machine mgr to not be able to find it.

The fix was to change the associated xml file in /etc/libvirt/qemu/:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source file=[new location/name].img'/>
```

For the change to take effort you need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out looking at the manuals for a fair few commands, the following command has worked

virt-install --name=WindowsXPIE6 --ram=512 --file=/media/Filestore/virtual_machines/WindowsXPIE6.img --import

--name is the name (label) of the Virtual Machine
--ram is the amount of RAM in mb
--file is the location of the .img file
--import is to tell QEMU to use an existing disk image

Answer (score 0):

You may find the the location of your server image:

```
$ find / -iname server.img
```

After run qemu from command line as :

```
$ qemu -boot c -hda server.img -net nic -net tap
```